# How to catch a command after "start" when a new user connects to a bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, pyrogram

I want to be able to handle a command like this:

```
https://t.me/MyBot?start=aff_1234
```

How will I do it? I've tried this and it hasn't worked:

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters

# ......
# ......

c = Client("bot"...)
hd = MessageHandler(main_handler)
c.add_handler(hd)

# ......

async def main_handler(client, message):
    try:
        # when a new user connects as
        # https://t.me/MyBot?start=aff_1234
        # this will never get fired
        # why not?

        print("debug #1")
        if message.text.startswith('/start'):
          parts = message.text.split('=aff_')
          # ..............
```

Comment: Use this https://github.com/Ripeey/Conversation-Pyrogram module .

Answer (score 0):

#### please read the [pyrogram documentation](https://docs.pyrogram.org) to avoid mistakes

first of all, use app.on_message to handle message.

you can do that using regex

example:

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters
app = Client("bot", ...)

@app.on_message(filters.regex(r'^/start aff_(\d+)'))
def handler(client, message):
    number = message.matches[0].group(1)
```